# How to attach a google doc file as Microsoft Word doc

Tags: email, google-apps-script, ms-word, attachment

My first time here in Stack overflow.  I'm just an amateur programmer trying to learn Google Apps script.  I created a google form to get answers from users. I have transferred the answers to a google doc formatted according to our use in the office. I need to email the google doc back to the for user in microsoft word format. Sending as pdf is not a problem, but msword is a bit tricky.

I tried copying the recommendations i found here but I can't seem to get it to run.  I hope someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong and what i need to doe. here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
`doc.saveAndClose(); // end of the transfer from google sheet to google doc. now to email...

  var filename= ts+"-"+c_name1;

  var compfile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);

  if (!compfile.hasNext()) 
  {
    console.error("Could not open file "+filename);
    return;
  }

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email_message');

  var message = template.evaluate().getContent();


   MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:em, 
    subject: "Automated Complaint Assistant", 
    htmlBody: message,
    attachments: compfile.next()})  // attachment is pdf file type. HOW TO SEND AS WORD?
```

`

I tried this function i found here:

```
`function EmailCompAsWordDoc(email, name, newCopyID) {

  var subject = "Word version of Complaint"; 
  var body = "\n\nHere is the Microsoft Word version of the draft Complaint";  
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' + newCopyID +         '&exportFormat=docx';
  var options = {
      headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
      }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var doc = response.getBlob();

  //Create the docx file in my TEMP folder in Google Drive and send
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(doc).setName('Draft Complaint '+ name + '.docx');
  DriveApp.getFolderById('<ID of my TEMP folder in Google Drive>').addFile(file);   
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());

  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      Body: body,
      attachments:[blob]     
    });  

  //Remove the docx file from the TEMP folder
  DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}


var compid = DriveApp.getFileById(filename.getId()) // error here. How to get the file ID for use by this custom function??

EmailCompAsWordDoc(em, c_name1, compid)
```

`

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. So, can you provide the detail of `I tried copying the recommendations i found here but I can't seem to get it to run.`?

Comment: Yes sir, i provided the details above. It's the EmailCompAsWordDoc function that i copied from one of the answers here.  I pasted the code above. i get the error "filename.getId is not a function".

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `filename.getId is not a function`, what is `filename` in your bottom script? In your bottom script, `filename` is not declared. But, when `filename` is not declared, I think that a different error message is shown. So, in this case, I think that it is required to know your whole script to correctly replicate your current issue. Can you provide it? I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for the attention sir.  filename is a string that contains the file name of the google doc i want to attach to the email. 

I saved the entire script in a text file and uploaded to my one drive. here's the link. 
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AqVjAy0YTAiBr8JXVccDNCYyG9Refg?e=FTODwG

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided script, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your provided script, I understood that the value of `filename` is the string value of `var filename = ts + "-" + c_name1;`. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue of `filename.getId is not a function`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var compid = DriveApp.getFileById(filename.getId())
```

#### To:

```
var compid = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename).next().getId();
```

- In this case, it supposes that the values of `filename` and `em` and `c_name1` of `EmailCompAsWordDoc(em, c_name1, compid)` are valid values. Please be careful about this.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! 

Thanks a million Tanaike! the solution is so obvious now! i had to use next()!

Learned a lot.  thanks!

Comment: @Anthony Thank you for replying and testing it. I could correctly understand your question by your cooperation. Thank you, too.