# Google App Script: Send email with attachment from google form response

Tags: google-apps-script

Previously I've made a script to generate .docx file from google form responses (one file for each google form responses) and it's uploaded to a google drive folder, and now I want the generated files emailed to the respondent's email.

I've tried this script:

```
function sendEmail(e){
  var respondentName = e.values[2];
  var clientName = e.values[3];
  var email = e.values[24];
  var subject = "Order details " + clientName;
  var message = "Thank you " + respondentName + " for submitting your form. Order under the name " + clientName + " has been recorded.";
  var waiver = DriveApp.getFileById("");
  var liabilityWaiver = waiver.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {attachments:[liabilityWaiver]});
}
```

Now my problem is because the file id for each .docx file generated by the other script is different I can't figure what script should I put instead of the getFileById("").

Here's the script that generates the .docx file

```
function autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm(e) {
  var activityDate = e.values[1];
  var respondentName = e.values[2]
  var clientName = e.values[3];
  var clientAddress = e.values[4];
  var clientPhoneNumber = e.values[5];
  var a = e.values[6];
  var b = e.values[7];
  var c = e.values[8];
  var d = e.values[9];
  var e = e.values[10];
  var f = e.values[11];
  var g = e.values[12];
  var h = e.values[13];
  var i = e.values[14];
  var j = e.values[15];
  var k = e.values[16];
  var l = e.values[17];
  var m = e.values[18];
  var n = e.values[19];
  var o = e.values[20];
  var p = e.values[21];
  var q = e.values[22];
  var r = e.values[23];

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("templatefileid");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderdestinationid");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy('Order details ' + client name + ' - ' + a, templateResponseFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{ActivityDate}}", activityDate);
  body.replaceText("{{ClientName}", clientName);
  body.replaceText("{{ClientAddress}}", clientAddress);
  body.replaceText("{{ClinetPhoneNumber}}", clientPhoneNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{A}}", a);
  body.replaceText("{{B}}", b);
  body.replaceText("{{C}}", c);
  body.replaceText("{{D}}", d);
  body.replaceText("{{E}}", e);
  body.replaceText("{{F}}", f);
  body.replaceText("{{G}}", g);
  body.replaceText("{{H}}", h);
  body.replaceText("{{I}}", i);
  body.replaceText("{{J}}", j);
  body.replaceText("{{K}}", k);
  body.replaceText("{{L}}", l);
  body.replaceText("{{M}}", m);
  body.replaceText("{{N}}", n);
  body.replaceText("{{O}}", o);
  body.replaceText("{{P}}", p);
  body.replaceText("{{Q}}", q);
  body.replaceText("{{R}}", r);
  body.replaceText("{{RespondentName}}", respondentName);

  doc.saveAndClose();
  
}
```

The data fields are (from left to right):

> Timestamp, Activity Date, Respondent's Name, Client's Name, Client's Address, Client's Phone Number,  A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, Respondent's Email Address

and for the form submissions are just a text answer.

Comment: `I want the generated files emailed to the respondent's email` - Would you please edit your question to include the script that generates/generated the .docx file and uploaded to a google drive folder, and also provide the form submission data fields, AND a sample of form submissions.

Comment: I can't really disclose all variable of the script but I'll try changing the unnecessary confidential variables by an alphabet, I hope it still works for you

Comment: @Tedinoz I've edited the question with some unnecessary variables and questions substituted by an alphabet due to confidentiality, I'm sorry and also I hope it still works for you.

Comment: Your form looks like customer orders so we need to identify a **unique** "value". But if customer lodges several orders on the same day, all the known fields (`Activity Date`, `Respondent's Name`, `Client's Name`, `Client's Address`, `Client's Phone Number` and `Respondent's Email Address`) would be identical - i.e. nothing unique. OTOH, what is `a`? You use it in your file name (`'Order details ' + client name + ' - ' + a`). I'm guessing it is a product code/name/id; is it a unique value? We could use "folder.getFilesByName(name)" to get the matching file.

Comment: There's nearly no chance that there will be several orders on the same day under one client's name, OTOH the 'a' is sort of like a store branch name and each branch will have 2-3 respondents, will that work?

Comment: So the name of the document (`'Order details ' + client name + ' - ' + a`) isn't unique either. `nearly no chance that there will be several orders on the same day under one client's name` - OK, then any combination of Activity Date and the Client Name should be unique. Well.. let's see if we can find that in a document :)

Comment: Every respondent have a unique user code but it's not in the Google Form yet, I can add a section for it. Let's just make it as 'respondentCode' and put it in the very right of the data field, after Respondent's Email Address. Will that work?

Comment: `now I want the generated files emailed to the respondent's email.` Would you please clarify this statement. Do you mean 1) for **new** submissions you want to create a word doc and email the doc (as a PDF) to the recipient? or 2) for all **existing** submissions, email the doc (as a PDF) to the recipient? or 3) both 1 & 2 or 4) something else?

Comment: What I want is exactly like point 1, for new submissions I want to create a word doc and email the doc (as a PDF) to the recipient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Google Form that branch/stores use to lodge orders. For each form submission, you want to:

- create an order form by merging the submission with a Google Docs template,
- send a confirmation email to the branch/store attaching a PDF copy of the merged Google Doc

You have two scripts (`sendEmail` and `autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm`) but you are unable to combine the two.

The following answer takes the OP scripts and combines them. There are several minor changes but the key aspects are:

- The installable `onFormSubmit` trigger is `sendEmail`
- **sendEmail**

  - `var docId = autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm(e)`

    - `sendEmail` begins by calling `autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm` (to create the merged document)
    - note that Event Objects are passed on
  - `var waiver = DriveApp.getFileById(docId)`

    - the document ID of the merged Google Doc is returned and used to create the PDF attachment
- **autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm**

  - insert the File ID for the Google Doc Template
  - insert the Folder ID for the destination folder
  - `return docId`

    - having created the merged document, the function ends by returning the document Id to `sendEmail`

---

```
function sendEmail(e){

  // get the doc ID for merged Google Doc
  var docId = autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm(e)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Autofill returned doc id = "+docId)

  var respondentName = e.values[2];
  var clientName = e.values[3];
  var email = e.values[24];
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Respondent name = "+respondentName+", Client name = "+clientName+", Email address= "+email)
  var subject = "Order details " + clientName;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Subject: "+subject)
  var message = "Thank you " + respondentName + " for submitting your form. Order under the name " + clientName + " has been recorded.";
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Message: "+message)
  var waiver = DriveApp.getFileById(docId);

  var liabilityWaiver = waiver.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {attachments:[liabilityWaiver]});
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: mail sent")
}

function autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm(e) {

  // this function is called by sendEmail(e)

  var activityDate = e.values[1];
  var respondentName = e.values[2]
  var clientName = e.values[3];
  var clientAddress = e.values[4];
  var clientPhoneNumber = e.values[5];
  var a = e.values[6];
  var b = e.values[7];
  var c = e.values[8];
  var d = e.values[9];
  var e = e.values[10];
  var f = e.values[11];
  var g = e.values[12];
  var h = e.values[13];
  var i = e.values[14];
  var j = e.values[15];
  var k = e.values[16];
  var l = e.values[17];
  var m = e.values[18];
  var n = e.values[19];
  var o = e.values[20];
  var p = e.values[21];
  var q = e.values[22];
  var r = e.values[23];


  var templatefileid = "<<insert Google Doc Template: file ID >>"
  var folderdestinationid = "<<insert Folder ID of destination folder>>"
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(templatefileid);
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderdestinationid);

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy('Order details ' + clientName + ' - ' + a, templateResponseFolder);
  var docId = copy.getId()
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{ActivityDate}}", activityDate);
  body.replaceText("{{RespondentName}}", respondentName);
  body.replaceText("{{ClientName}}", clientName);
  body.replaceText("{{ClientAddress}}", clientAddress);
  body.replaceText("{{ClientPhoneNumber}}", clientPhoneNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{A}}", a);
  body.replaceText("{{B}}", b);
  body.replaceText("{{C}}", c);
  body.replaceText("{{D}}", d);
  body.replaceText("{{E}}", e);
  body.replaceText("{{F}}", f);
  body.replaceText("{{G}}", g);
  body.replaceText("{{H}}", h);
  body.replaceText("{{I}}", i);
  body.replaceText("{{J}}", j);
  body.replaceText("{{K}}", k);
  body.replaceText("{{L}}", l);
  body.replaceText("{{M}}", m);
  body.replaceText("{{N}}", n);
  body.replaceText("{{O}}", o);
  body.replaceText("{{P}}", p);
  body.replaceText("{{Q}}", q);
  body.replaceText("{{R}}", r);

  doc.saveAndClose();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Done")
  return docId

}
```

Comment: Gosh! Thank you so much, it works! I have a follow-up question about the script:
1. If I want to make the emailed file still in .docx file, which part of the script should I delete?
2. Speaking of the respondent's unique user code that we discussed earlier, is it still needed for the script to work?

Comment: `If I want to make the emailed file still in .docx file` Not really sure what this means; perhaps you mean that you want to sent the doc file without creating a PDF. First, it is a Google Docs file NOT a "docx" file (that's Word format). Second, you wouldn't send an attachment, you'd just send a copy of the file URL (which means that you'd have to use [getUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl). `respondent's unique user code that we discussed earlier, is it still needed for the script to work?` No.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was I want to send the file in word format instead of pdf, or use getUrl, which part should I delete/replace

Comment: A recent solution from @Tanaike. [Attach a doc file as docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75358175/how-to-attach-a-google-doc-file-as-microsoft-word-doc)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for the solution by @Tanaike as reference. After I read it, I still can't figure which part exactly should I replace/add to the current script, can you help me once again with this?

Comment: `I still can't figure which part exactly should I replace/add to the current script` It's not a 2 minute solution but I suggest that you are trying to do too much. In the first instance, don't try and send an email; just take `EmailCompAsWordDoc` (from the Tanaike question, as amended), remove the email code, and try to convert a doc file to docx. You could start by manually inserting the fileID/filename manually; then move on to passing on that information from `autoFillGoogleDocsFromForm`. If you're still struggling, then post a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I still can't figure it out, I'll post a new question.