# create pdf from doc template on update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a google sheet with 22 columns, the sheets are edited using google app script html template, i need to update a google doc template from the google sheet data on edit.
i have the following functions in the sheet

````
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot');
function UpdateRecord
      dataSheet.getRange(seq_id+1, 2).setValue(name);
      dataSheet.getRange(seq_id+1, 3).setNumberFormat('@STRING@').setValue(personId);
      //dataSheet.getRange(seq_id+1, 3).setValue(personId);
      //dataSheet.getRange(seq_id+1, 4).setValue(curr_degree);
      //dataSheet.getRange(seq_id+1, 5).setValue(up_curr_court);
function searchRecords(personId,password)
  var passcode = 0;
  if (personId == '')
    return returnRows;
  readIds = dataSheet.getRange("C2:C"+getLastRow).getValues();
  for(i = 0; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  return returnRows;```

i need a function to edit a google doc template with the same data edited to tho google sheet on edit and save the google doc using one of the variables from the code and the current date to a folder in google drive, thanks and best regards
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkF7o.png
````

Comment: Hi, i have deployed data entry form that submits data to a google sheet, i need this data to be updated in a google doc as well on edit

Comment: i added a picture with the code am using

Comment: Does this Q&A help? [Google App Script: Send email with attachment from google form response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76268826/1330560)